# Finding no. of shifts in Insertion sort for large inputs in C

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to write a program that counts the number of swaps made by insertion sort. My program works on small inputs, but produces the wrong answer on large inputs. I'm also not sure how to use the `long int` type.

This problem came up in a setting described at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxOMrMV58jtmNF9EcUNQNGpreDQ/edit?usp=sharing

Input is given as

```
   The first line contains the number of test cases T. T test cases follow. 
   The first line for each case contains N, the number of elements to be sorted. 
   The next line contains N integers a[1],a[2]...,a[N].
```

Code I used is

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    int insertionSort(int ar_size,int *  ar)
    {

        int i,j,t,temp,count;
        count=0;
        int n=ar_size;

        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)            
        {
           j=i;
           while(ar[j+1]<ar[j])
           {
               temp=ar[j+1];
               ar[j+1]=ar[j];
               ar[j]=temp;
               j--;

               count++;
             }

        }
        return count;
    }


int main() 
{
    int _ar_size,tc,i,_ar_i;
    scanf("%d", &tc);

     int sum=0;

     for(i=0;i<tc;i++)
     {

         scanf("%d", &_ar_size);
         int *_ar;
         _ar=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*_ar_size);
         for(_ar_i = 0; _ar_i < _ar_size; _ar_i++) 
         {
            scanf("%d", &_ar[_ar_i]);
         }

         sum=insertionSort(_ar_size, _ar);

         printf("%d\n",sum);

      }

       return 0;
  }
```

Comment: are you overflowing int?

Comment: @GradyPlayer yes it is in 1st case no.of inputs are 65911 and in third one 100,000 inputs are taken.Without using long it is giving correct output for small values, when I used long int  it is not giving correct output for small values also .Ex:take input as 1  5   2 1 3 1 2 its ouput is 4 when i use this code and its output is 10 when i use long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues that I currently see with the solution you have.

First, there's an issue brought up in the comments about integer overflow. On most systems, the `int` type can hold numbers up through 2<sup>31</sup> - 1. In insertion sort, the number of swaps that need to be made in the worst case on an array of length n is n(n - 1) / 2 (details later), so for an array of size 2<sup>17</sup>, you may end up not being able to store the number of swaps that you need inside an `int`. To address this, consider using a larger integer type. For example, the `uint64_t` type can store numbers up to roughly 10<sup>18</sup>, which should be good enough to store the answer for arrays up to length around 10<sup>9</sup>. You mentioned that you're not sure how to use it, but the good news is that it's not that hard. Just add the line

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

(for C) or

```
#include <cstdint>
```

(for C++) to the top of your program. After that, you should just be able to use `uint64_t` in place of `int` without making any other modifications and everything should work out just fine.

Next, there's an issue of efficiency. The code you've posted essentially runs insertion sort and therefore takes time O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst-case. For large inputs - say, inputs around size 10<sup>8</sup> - this is prohibitively expensive. Amazingly, though, you can actually determine how many swaps insertion sort will make without actually running insertion sort.

In insertion sort, the number of swaps made is equal to the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) that exist in the input array (an inversion is a pair of elements that are out of order). There's a [beautiful divide-and-conquer algorithm for counting inversions](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/cs423/lectures/divide-and-conquer-4up.pdf) that runs in time O(n log n), which likely will scale up to work on much larger inputs than just running insertion sort. I think that the "best" answer to this question would be to use this algorithm, while taking care to use the `uint64_t` type or some other type like it, since it will make your algorithm work correctly on much larger inputs.